# Android - get EditBox in hierarchically view

Tags: java, android

I created EditBox in LinearLayout dynamically. Here is my code:

```
    final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_relative);
    counter = 0;
    addButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter += 1;
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.setTag(CONSTANT_LAYOUT + counter);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);


            EditText etProduct = new EditText(view.getContext());
            etProduct.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            etProduct.setTag(counter);

            ll.addView(etProduct);
            mainLayout.addView(ll);

      }
```

And it works like a charm. Whenever I click on specific button, It create new linear layout , EditBox in there and *counter* increase one by one and user can add value in *EditBox*es.

Now, I want to get value of *EditBox*es, I've tried like :

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            for (int i=0 ; i<counter ; i++) {                    

                View lr = mainLayout.findViewWithTag(CONSTANT_LAYOUT+i);
                EditText et = (EditText)lr.findViewWithTag(counter);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

But I got an error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.myapp, PID: 15055
>                                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View
>   android.view.View.findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

Any suggestion?

Comment: No view at zero index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to start your `for` `loop` by 1 instead of 0 and please try to give tag value more than 1 or `equal` to 1 not 0.

```
        for (int i=1 ; i<=counter ; i++) {   // and condition should be i<=counter  = instead of less than               

            View lr = mainLayout.findViewWithTag(CONSTANT_LAYOUT+i);
            EditText et = (EditText)lr.findViewWithTag(counter);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is starting from zero.

```
for (int i=0 ; i<counter ; i++) {
   // No value for Zero index.
}
```

At a time of setting tag, you are adding +1. So first value will be 1 not 0.

```
counter += 1; // Default value of counter is zero
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added new `LinearLayout` in your Root `LinearLayout`  Also you can `setId()` to your newly created `LinearLayout` rather `setTag()` that also work fine for you .

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll.setId(CONSTANT_LAYOUT + counter);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);


            EditText etProduct = new EditText(view.getContext());
            etProduct.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            etProduct.setId(counter);

            ll.addView(etProduct);
            mainLayout.addView(ll);
```

And

```
for (int i=0 ; i<counter ; i++) {                    

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout )mainLayout.findViewById(CONSTANT_LAYOUT+i);
                EditText et = (EditText)ll .findViewById(counter);
            }
```

Comment: my CONSTANT_LAYOUT is string so I cannot setId(string)